# MPEG-DASH Adaptive Streaming with HTML5 is not working in windows Chrome/Mozilla

Tags: javascript, html, azure, video-streaming, mpeg-dash

I am completely new in MPEG-DASH Adaptive Streaming . I am trying to create a Video player with `dash.js` in browser . I have referenced some of the useful `MPEG-DASH` `Adaptive Streaming` documents . Those links are

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-embed-mpeg-dash-in-html5#creating-the-html-page
- https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js

With the above documents , i have created a sample HTML file .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Adaptive Streaming in HTML5</title>
    <style>
        video {
        width: 640px;
        height: 360px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Adaptive Streaming with HTML5</h1>
        <video id="videoplayer" controls></video>
    <div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <!-- DASH-AVC/265 reference implementation -->
    <script src="https://cdn.dashjs.org/latest/dash.all.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    <!--setup the video element and attach it to the Dash player-->
            (function(){
                var url = "https://dash.akamaized.net/envivio/EnvivioDash3/manifest.mpd";
                var player = dashjs.MediaPlayer().create();
                player.initialize(document.querySelector("#videoPlayer"), url, true);
            })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But after running on `chrome (Version 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit))` and `mozilla (version 57.0 (64-bit))` , I couldn't see any video playing in this player . This is the output screenshot

[image]

I am trying to run locally on my browser . Will it make any problem ? After clicking play button , i couldn't see any video on that . In `Mozilla` browser i can see following

```
[dash.js 2.6.4] MediaPlayer has been initialized

The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. 
The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. 
The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.
```

But the script https://cdn.dashjs.org/latest/dash.all.min.js is working fine too . Also when i add `https://dash.akamaized.net/envivio/EnvivioDash3/manifest.mpd` URL in https://reference.dashif.org/dash.js/1.4.0/samples/dash-if-reference-player/index.html video player , it is working fine .

Actually what is i am missing here ? Any suggestions or help ?

Answer (score 5):

Attribute values are **case-sensitive** in HTML documents.

So, this would work if you change the `<video>` element to:

```
<video id="videoPlayer" controls></video>
```

Answer (score 1):

HLS is automatically supported by HTML5, but MPEG-DASH is not. This means that some browsers or apps cannot play MPEG-DASH video streams, even on non-Apple devices.

Read [HLS vs Dash in this link](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/video/what-is-mpeg-dash/)